# Meyers Singleton : static keyword confusion

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, singleton

Consider a following piece of code which is essentially an example of Meyer's singleton (hopefully)

```
static const std::string& foo() // Line 1
{
   static std::string str("foo");
   return str;
}
```

Is static keyword mentioned in the Line 1 meaningless ? If so why ?

Comment: @Evg The first line is the function signature. Not the static variable.

Comment: @Evg Garbage value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is static keyword mentioned in the Line 1 meaningless ? If so why ?

It is not meaningless, if you need it or not depend on your situation. `static` in C++ means different thing in different context, in this case it makes this function only available on current compilation unit. Modern way to do it in C++ - to put the function into anonymous namespace.